# How to extract items from a subarray and push them to the main array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a type speed test and, for this, I'll need to get a random item from an array, split every letter, push it to a new one and re-do this several times. But, every time I split the string from the first array, returns to my new array a subarray, instead of just letters. How can I extract everything from the subarrays and put into my main array?

```
var Pokemon = ["Bulbasaur","Ivysaur","Venusaur","Charmander","Charmeleon","Charizard","Squirtle","Wartortle","Blastoise","Caterpie","Metapod","Butterfree","Weedle","Kakuna","Beedrill","Pidgey","Pidgeotto","Pidgeot","Rattata","Raticate","Spearow","Fearow","Ekans","Arbok","Pikachu","Raichu","Sandshrew","Sandslash","Nidoran","Nidorina","Nidoqueen","Nidoran","Nidorino","Nidoking","Clefairy","Clefable","Vulpix","Ninetales","Jigglypuff","Wigglytuff","Zubat","Golbat","Oddish","Gloom","Vileplume","Paras","Parasect","Venonat","Venomoth","Diglett","Dugtrio","Meowth","Persian","Psyduck","Golduck","Mankey","Primeape","Growlithe","Arcanine","Poliwag","Poliwhirl","Poliwrath","Abra","Kadabra","Alakazam","Machop","Machoke","Machamp","Bellsprout","Weepinbell","Victreebel","Tentacool","Tentacruel","Geodude","Graveler","Golem","Ponyta","Rapidash","Slowpoke","Slowbro","Magnemite","Magneton","Farfetch'd","Doduo","Dodrio","Seel","Dewgong","Grimer","Muk","Shellder","Cloyster","Gastly","Haunter","Gengar","Onix","Drowzee","Hypno","Krabby","Kingler","Voltorb","Electrode","Exeggcute","Exeggutor","Cubone","Marowak","Hitmonlee","Hitmonchan","Lickitung","Koffing","Weezing","Rhyhorn","Rhydon","Chansey","Tangela","Kangaskhan","Horsea","Seadra","Goldeen","Seaking","Staryu","Starmie","Mr. Mime","Scyther","Jynx","Electabuzz","Magmar","Pinsir","Tauros","Magikarp","Gyarados","Lapras","Ditto","Eevee","Vaporeon","Jolteon","Flareon","Porygon","Omanyte","Omastar","Kabuto","Kabutops","Aerodactyl","Snorlax","Articuno","Zapdos","Moltres","Dratini","Dragonair","Dragonite","Mewtwo","Mew"];

var wordsToWrite = []
var letterToWrite = []

function sortWords(){
    var numberSorted = Math.floor(Math.random() * (151 - 1)) + 1;
    wordsToWrite.push(Pokemon[numberSorted]);
}

var times = 150;
for(var i=0; i < times; i++){
    sortWords()
}

console.log(wordsToWrite)

for(var k=0; k < wordsToWrite.length; k++){
    var x = wordsToWrite[k];
    var y = x.split('');
    letterToWrite.push(y)
}


console.log(letterToWrite)

console.log(letterToWrite[14])
```

For example, when I try to console.log the 14th element from my array letterToWrite, it shows my entire word, and not the single letter that I want. What can I do to extract the letters from the subarray and displays it on the main array?

Comment: What supposed to be the correct output?

Comment: Now my main array is: {{"P", "i", "k", "a", "c", "h", "u"}, {"B", "u", "l", "b", "a", "s", "a", "u", "r"}, {...}...}, but it should be {"P", "i", "k", "a", "c", "h", "u", "B", "u", "l", "b", "a", "s", "a", "u", "r", ...}

Answer (score 1):

```
letterToWrite = [...letterToWrite, y]
```

instead of `letterToWrite.push(y)`
and `...` is called `spread operator`. [Check](https://newbedev.com/typescript-spread-operator-in-javascript-w3schools-code-example) for more

Comment: I think he needs something like: `for letter in y lettertowrite.push(letter)`

Comment: same stuff but with spread operator i think its more readable

Answer (score 0):

After a long try, I could resolve it and I'll post to help if anyone had the same question.

```
var Pokemon = ["Bulbasaur","Ivysaur","Venusaur","Charmander","Charmeleon","Charizard","Squirtle","Wartortle","Blastoise","Caterpie","Metapod","Butterfree","Weedle","Kakuna","Beedrill","Pidgey","Pidgeotto","Pidgeot","Rattata","Raticate","Spearow","Fearow","Ekans","Arbok","Pikachu","Raichu","Sandshrew","Sandslash","Nidoran","Nidorina","Nidoqueen","Nidoran","Nidorino","Nidoking","Clefairy","Clefable","Vulpix","Ninetales","Jigglypuff","Wigglytuff","Zubat","Golbat","Oddish","Gloom","Vileplume","Paras","Parasect","Venonat","Venomoth","Diglett","Dugtrio","Meowth","Persian","Psyduck","Golduck","Mankey","Primeape","Growlithe","Arcanine","Poliwag","Poliwhirl","Poliwrath","Abra","Kadabra","Alakazam","Machop","Machoke","Machamp","Bellsprout","Weepinbell","Victreebel","Tentacool","Tentacruel","Geodude","Graveler","Golem","Ponyta","Rapidash","Slowpoke","Slowbro","Magnemite","Magneton","Farfetch'd","Doduo","Dodrio","Seel","Dewgong","Grimer","Muk","Shellder","Cloyster","Gastly","Haunter","Gengar","Onix","Drowzee","Hypno","Krabby","Kingler","Voltorb","Electrode","Exeggcute","Exeggutor","Cubone","Marowak","Hitmonlee","Hitmonchan","Lickitung","Koffing","Weezing","Rhyhorn","Rhydon","Chansey","Tangela","Kangaskhan","Horsea","Seadra","Goldeen","Seaking","Staryu","Starmie","Mr. Mime","Scyther","Jynx","Electabuzz","Magmar","Pinsir","Tauros","Magikarp","Gyarados","Lapras","Ditto","Eevee","Vaporeon","Jolteon","Flareon","Porygon","Omanyte","Omastar","Kabuto","Kabutops","Aerodactyl","Snorlax","Articuno","Zapdos","Moltres","Dratini","Dragonair","Dragonite","Mewtwo","Mew"];

var characterToWrite = []

function sortWords(){
    var numberSorted = Math.floor(Math.random() * (151 - 1)) + 1;
    var x = Pokemon[numberSorted];
    for(var k=0; k < x.length; k++){
        charac = x[k];
        characterToWrite.push(charac)
    }

}

var times = 150;
for(var i=0; i < times; i++){
    sortWords()
}


console.log(characterToWrite)
```